# How to mark checkboxes in grid from data?

Tags: php, user-interface, atk4

I know how to select some rows from a grid as indicated here:
http://agiletoolkit.org/blog/how-to-select-elements-in-a-grid/

But I want to do the opposite, I want to have a grid, with selectable column, where I want to have checked the rows with certain ids from database, and then be able to unselect some or select a new one.

Is there a "prefered" method to do that in Agile Toolkit?

Answer (score 1):

i'll make this short just to answer the question.

to preselect checkboxes on Grid Basic or MVC Grid, you just need to fill-in the values in the accompanying Form's `selected` Form_Field, example:

```
 class page_gridcheckboxestest extends Page {
    function init() {
       parent::init();

       $g = $this->add('MVCGrid');
       $g->setModel('Employees');

       $f = $this->add('Form');
       $f->addField('hidden','selected');

       $preselect = array(1,2,3,4,5); // array of preselected ids
       $f->getElement('selected')->set(json_encode($preselect));

       $g->addSelectable($f->getElement('selected'));
    }
 }
```

the array of preselected ids has to be in JSON format for this to work.